# The query has been canceled because the estimated cost of this query (15) exceeds the configured threshold of 12. Contact the system administrator

Tags: sql, sql-server

A few days ago I started getting the following error when running even simple queries in Sql Server Management Studio

> The query has been canceled because the estimated cost of this query (15) exceeds the configured threshold of 12. Contact the system administrator.

It happens even for basic queries like

```
select count(*) from Table where Column in (1,2,3)
```

I don't have this issue when executing the select from HeidiSQL. Neither my colleagues have this error. I have the error even when trying to execute it on local machine. I uninstalled the SSMS, reinstalled, repaired, reset. Still no result. Can't figure out what is broken on my machine.

LE: the database is very small, so I am sure that the returned results are way below any limit

Comment: Did you contact the system administrator?

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Query Execution -> SQL Server -> Advanced and check if `SET QUERY_GOVERNOR_COST_LIMIT` has been assigned a value. If not, then it's a server-side resource governor configuration.

Comment: @JeroenMostert this was it. I set it to 0, assuming this means disabled and now everything works. I can't explain how this value was changed, I was not even aware of its existence. All I found on internet was related to governor limits server side, which are disabled. You can post it as an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the DBA has configured the server to disallow expensive queries.  See

[Configure the query governor cost limit Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-query-governor-cost-limit-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017)

A query like

```
select count(*) 
from Table 
where Column in (1,2,3)
```

can be quite expensive, as it requires a complete scan of some index containing `Column`, and if no "skinny" index has that column, then it requires a complete table scan.

Answer (score 1):

The query has been canceled because the estimated cost of this query (15) exceeds the configured threshold of 12. Contact the system administrator
in stored procedure after create or alter

```
set query_governor_cost_limit 150000
```